# Translating "I'm bad with [remembering] something"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English, you can say:

- I'm horrible with names.
- I'm bad with faces.
- I'm really bad with directions.

What is the most natural way in Spanish of expressing that you are bad at remembering something?

Comment: Actually we wouldn't even say "I'm bad **with** XYZing" in English. We would say "I'm bad **at** XYZing".

Comment: @hippietrail: Hmm, now there's a question for EL&U :)  I'd say "I'm bad with names" not "I'm bad at names" (Western US). I *would* say "I'm bad at swimming" though.

Comment: For "names" both sound good to me (Australia) but anything I can think of with a verb ending in "-ing" I would only say "at". But sure why not ask on EL&U? (-:

Comment: [Done](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49905/bad-with-something-or-bad-at-something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two basic ways:

> Se me da mal *algo* / *algo* se me da mal.
>
> No se me da muy bien *algo* / *algo* se me da muy bien

You can modify the adverb (*mal*/*bien* in this case) to represent how bad you're at it, or for personal preference:

- mal - muy mal - bastante mal - fatal - como el culo (very vulgar)
- bien - muy bien - nada bien

The other ways is:

> Soy bastante malo *haciendo algo*
>
> No soy muy bueno *haciendo algo*

You can also change the adverb like so:

- malo - bastante malo - realmente malo - malisimo - terrible
- bueno - muy bueno - buenisimo - genial

These are just two ways, but I'm sure there are plenty more.

Answer (score 2):

Usually:

> Tengo (muy) mala memoria para (whatever)

Answer (score 1):

You can also say:

> Soy muy malo con/para (whatever)
>
> Soy fatal (affected/posh) para las caras/los nombres or recordar
>   (idem)